# How to remove the token `[None]` from the album field of the songs and replace None with whitespaces?

Tags: c++, vector

**The function:**

`void cleanAlbum()`

removes the token `[None]` from the album field of the songs that do not have a valid album.

I have a vector of Songs called ***collection*** and there are strings like

> string artist;
>
> string album;
>
> string song_name;

**I need to replace [None] with "     " (6 whitespaces) in this collection for albums with name "[None]"**

My code doesn't work:

```
     replace_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), "[None]", "      ");
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to compare, your Song class to a string in your code. That won't work. If I were you I'd add a boolean variable to your Song class called isEmpty which will be true in the case where your were entering "[None]" and a function called empty() which returns true if the song is empty.

Using this your code should look like:

```
replace_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), empty, "      ");
```

Here is a link to the documentation on the replace_if function, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace_if/ empty() might have to not be a member function of the Song class for this to work, in which case I'd advise giving it a different name.