# Replace a string in a vector of structs C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, type-conversion

I am trying to replace a string in a vector of structs.

```
struct Song
{
    string artist;
    string title;
    string album;
    double m_price;
    string year;
    size_t length;
};

vector<Song> c_collection;
```

Then I used this loop to replace a string "[None]" in 'album' with 6 spaces:

```
for (auto& c : c_collection)
    {
        std::replace(c.album.begin(), c.album.end(), string("[None]"), string("      "));
    }
```

Compiler shows an error which says:

```
 "cannot convert from 'const_Ty' to 'char' with [  _Ty=std::string  ]".
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the vector, or the struct. Your replace is wrong. See the dupe for some ways of doing that.

Comment: Also, [please stop posting duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984907/how-to-remove-the-token-none-from-the-album-field-of-the-songs-and-replace-n).

Comment: You are trying to compare each char in album with a string  [None]. You need to compare album as a string with [None].

Comment: @stackoverblown How can I do this?

Comment: Directly compare the two like if ( c.album == "[None]" ) c.album = std::string("      ");